# How to check the cardinality of the intersection of a set

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I write because I have the following (easy) problem:
I'm modeling a problem that concerns networks, specifically, sets containing nodes of a network. My problem is this:
If I have a set in which there are *n* distinct values (for example nodes that send messages), if I receive in total $4n\over3$ messages, as I know that $ n < $ $4n\over3$ how do I prove that the **intersection** has cardinality as a minimum $n\over3$ (i.e., at least $n\over3$ of the messages were sent twice)?
I know it's trivial, but I can't understand what the mathematical process is to prove this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that $\frac n3$ messages are sent twice? It could be that all but one message have been sent at most once (perhaps even not at all) and just the one remaining message very often

Answer (score 0):

It's not true that at least $\frac n 3$ messages were sent twice. For example, for $n = 6$ you could receive messages $1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6$ - only one message sent more then once.

You can prove, hovewer, that at least $\frac n 3$ of messages you got you got more than once. Assume there are less than $\frac n 3$ messages such "n-plicates". Remove them from your set - you have set of more than $n$ messages at most $n$ of which are unique. From [pigeonhole princpile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) it follows at least one of remaining messages was got at least twice.